# Problemas na leitura e gravação

Tags: php, fopen, file-get-contents, file-put-contents

Supondo que se tenha um log de acesso, cada requisição vai criar ou incluir valores ao arquivo de log.

Simulando várias requisições via ajax, descobri que sempre ocorre algum problema. Se entrar no console do navegador e executar o código abaixo, será feita uma requisição dentro do loop.

```
setInterval(function()
{
    $('div').each(function()
    {
        $.get( 'url interna' , function( data )
        {
            $('html').text( 'data' )
        });
    })
} , 100 )
```

A cada requisição pelo ajax será gravado um arquivo de log, mas em um determinado ponto é disparado um erro tipo *Permission denied* ou *Invalid argument*. Já tentei via `file_get_contents`, `file_put_contents`, `fopen`, `fwrite` e sempre algum erro ocorre.

---

A manipulação dos arquivos funciona corretamente, eu escrevo e leio sem problemas. Fiz um loop em 1000 e nenhum erro ocorre durante a gravação.

```
for( $i = 1; $i <= 1000; $i++ )
{
    $fp = fopen( 'file.txt' , 'w' );
    fwrite( $fp , 'texto' );
    fclose( $fp );
}
```

---

Comment: Já checou as permissões do diretório?

Comment: @gmsantos, Manipulo os arquivos sem problema, nunca deu erro, somente no ajax que trava. Ele chega a gravar e sobrescrever, mas em algum ponto (que não sei qual nem o motivo) no loop do ajax retorna `Invalid argument`

Comment: Somente para teste, de um `chmod -R 777` no seu diretório

Comment: @gmsantos Não adiantou.

Comment: Não consegui reproduzir seu problema. Aqui funcionou sem nenhum problema.

Comment: [Vamos continuar essa discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19149/php-sopt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando o arquivo já está aberto por um processo você não pode editar ele em outro.

Exemplo: Se o **arquivo01.php** estiver com o arquivo aberto (fopen), o **arquivo02.php** ou até mesmo outro processo do **arquivo01.php** não poderá abrir ele enquanto o processo que está com ele aberto der um fclose ou ser morto pelo sistema operacional.

O seu loop não apresenta problemas porque você abre o arquivo fecha ele e assim por diante...

```
for( $i = 1; $i <= 1000; $i++ )
{
    $fp = fopen( 'file.txt' , 'w' ); //Abre o arquivo
    fwrite( $fp , 'texto' );
    fclose( $fp ); //Fecha o arquivo
}
```

> Para simular um erro de permission denied você pode usar o código abaixo...

```
$abre_arquivo =  fopen( 'file.txt' , 'w' ); //Ele foi aberto ou seja o espaço de memória esta reservado para uso da variável $abre_arquivo.
for( $i = 1; $i <= 1000; $i++ )
{
    $fp = fopen( 'file.txt' , 'w' ); //Abre o arquivo - Porém ele já esta aberto em outro processo.
    fwrite( $fp , 'texto' );
    fclose( $fp ); //Fecha o arquivo
}
```

Comment: É isso ai mesmo, obrigado

Comment: Não faz sentido a resposta ter resolvido seu problema porque de acordo com a explicação, você não teria de mudar nada. Certeza que você não esqueceu de mencionar alguma coisa ou não adicionou alguma coisa a mais que possa ter solucionado o problema?

Comment: @BrunoAugusto, a resposta foi uma explicação do problema, e nesse caso, a manipulação de um arquivo por múltiplas instâncias é um impedimento do PHP. Realmente não resolve o problema, mas diz o motivo de não poder fazer. Como não há solução, achei que a explicação poderia dar a questão por encerrada.

Comment: Mas estão havendo múltiplas instâncias? Porque a partir do momento que você encerra o recurso, a instância já não existe mais.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto, 2 ou mais simultâneas. Não há como 'enfileirar'. O loop pelo js simula isso.

Comment: E se você abrir o arquivo fora do loop, modificando o modo de abertura para **a**?

Comment: @BrunoAugusto, esse js é uma simulação que eu fiz, ele pode ser facilmente injetado em qualquer site pelo console do navegador. Já usei todos os modos de leitura e escrita e o php falha se já estiver aberto. Se você quiser pode fazer um teste local e te mando os codigos.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19440/discussion-between-papa-charlie-and-bruno-augusto).

Comment: Galera desculpem mais a pergunta era o porque acontecia o erro permission denied não como arruma lo, eu sei o porque de acontecer agora como contornar já é outra história (pergunta)

Comment: E não é o Php que faz isso. Essa resposta é do sistema operacional.

Comment: Um processo está com o arquivo aberto na hora que o Php tenta abrir novamente o S.O não permite

Comment: Como exemplo abram um doc do Word e tenta apaga ele. Isso são tratamentos do sistema operacional